# Using template in emailFields payload in publisher.setActionInputValues

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I am not able to send the email on Case.Email using template Id.

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: 'publisher.selectAction', 
        payload: { actionName: 'Case.Email'}}); 
        Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: 'publisher.setActionInputValues', 
        payload: {
               actionName: 'Case.Email',
               emailFields: {
                template: {id: id}, 
            }
               //emailTemplate:{id:id}
        }});
```

The above code injects template into quick action, Case.Email. On sending email we get the error as attached. We have compared logs when sending a static text or html and template with this code. Both are similar. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Error]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We got it working by passing 15 digit ID. Earlier we were passing 18 Digits. Thanks